# How does the rule of passport's 6 months validity to enter Colombia work?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, denial-of-entry, colombia

I will travel to Colombia soon. Colombia has a rule the passport must be valid for at least 6 months to enter. However, I find contradicting information.

Some websites recommend the passport to be valid for 6 months. Other websites say it's 6 months counted from the entry date, others 6 months from the date of planned leave.

My passport will be valid for more than 6 months on the day of entry, but will be about 12 days short on the day of leaving. Will I be denied entry?

Comment: What’s your citizenship?

Comment: Timatic (the database used by airlines to check passport and visa requirements) says “Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for the period of intended stay” for the 3 random citizenships I tried. There may be different rules in specific cases, but we would need more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have emailed the embassy of Colombia.

The answer was **passport should be valid for the duration of the stay in Colombia**. Thus the information found all over Internet that a passport have to be valid for at least 6 months in order to enter/leave Colombia is incorrect.

Comment: That may because some sites are taking possible extensions (or periods longer than 90 days) into account: [Entry requirements - Colombia travel advice - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/colombia/entry-requirements#entry-rules-in-response-to-coronavirus-covid-19): *As a visitor, you can’t remain in Colombia for more than **180 days in any 12 month period.***

Comment: Very interesting, we are leaving soon and our daughters passport is also valid for less than 6 months.  Which mail address did you use to ask this question?

Comment: cberlin@cancilleria.gov.co was the one that answered. I had no problem entering with my passport losing validity shortly after the return flight's date.